# Make an object delete itself with a macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have code that creates three identical objects, and gives them a macro to run when they are clicked. I need to make it so that they also delete themselves (or move themselves off screen) when they are clicked on!

I've already tried adding .delete in my ppMouseClick statement

```
Public Sub PopUpBattleTimes3()
BattleCounter = 0
SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (7)

Dim oShp1 As Shape
Dim oShp2 As Shape
Dim oShp3 As Shape


Dim valuex As Integer
Dim valuey As Integer

valuex = CInt(Int((800 * rnd()) + 10))
valuey = CInt(Int((500 * rnd()) + 10))
Set oShp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeActionButtonCustom, valuex, valuey, 80, 50)
oShp1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Object 1"
With oShp1.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    .Action = ppActionRunMacro
    .Run = "AddToCounter"
End With


valuex = CInt(Int((800 * rnd()) + 10))
valuey = CInt(Int((500 * rnd()) + 10))
Set oShp2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeActionButtonCustom, valuex, valuey, 80, 50)
oShp2.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Object2"
With oShp2.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    .Action = ppActionRunMacro
    .Run = "AddToCounter"
End With

valuex = CInt(Int((800 * rnd()) + 10))
valuey = CInt(Int((500 * rnd()) + 10))
Set oShp3 = ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeActionButtonCustom, valuex, valuey, 80, 50)
oShp3.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Object3"
With oShp1.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    .Action = ppActionRunMacro
    .Run = "AddToCounter"
End With
End Sub
```

I would really like it if there was some code I could put in my "AddToCounter" Macro or within this macro that would help delete (or move off screen) the object that was clicked on. Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: I added my answer (and you have a typo in the third button: "With oShp1 ..." should read "With oShp3"). Have fun designing your battle game :)

Comment: Is your code housed in a PPTM or PPSM file and does it only need to run in SlideShow view?  If so, you can assign the buttons Run Macro action settings and have them run a macro that starts like:  Sub SomeName(oSh As Shape). The rest of the macro code can do whatever you like with oSh, which will be a reference to the clicked shape. More detail and a workaround for when this fails on the Mac are on my PowerPoint FAQ site, here: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00141_Determine_which_shape_was_clicked.htm

Answer (score 0):

Add this please:

```
Public Sub AddToCounter(sh As Shape)
    sh.Delete
End Sub
```

If you give your buttons a non-default name within "PopUpBattleTimes3", e. g. `oShp1.name = "TEST1"` then you may use a `Select Case sh.Name` within your "AddToCounter" to handle different actions for each button.

Comment: Fine :) Please mark my answer as "accepted answer" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).